# Logging macro with stringstream creation in expansion

Tags: c++, boost, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void log(
        const char* argFile,
                int argLineNb,
                const char* argFunction,
                std::stringstream& argString) {
    std::cout << argFile << ":" << argLineNb << " " << argFunction
        << " " << argString.str()<< std::endl;
}


/**
 * \brief       Macro declarations
 */

#define LOG_TEST(f) \
                log(__FILE__, __LINE__, \
                        __FUNCTION__, (std::ostringstream << f))

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    LOG_TEST("HELLO");
    LOG_TEST("HELLO" << " !");

    return 0;
}
```

Problem is that I don't really know how to do that as I'm getting the following errors:

> invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::stringstream& {aka std::basic_stringstream&}' from expression of type 'std::basic_ostream::__ostream_type {aka std::basic_ostream

I don't know if there's a simpler way to do that with boost...

Here is source: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=222cbb23ea5162b16378b13a24fceb9e-4f0e144d2529f0880899ab58231ebbe3

Comment: You're passing a tempval `stringstream` to a function requiring a **non-const** reference. All but a few compilers will not let you do that, as it is non-standard. The ones most-known for allowing it are Microsoft's. Almost everyone else will not.

Comment: @tacp if you're going to paste code from the OP's link, at least paste it *verbatim*. The code you posted is not the same as the code on the link provided in the question. His code has a `std::stringstream()` in the log macro, the code you pasted has `std::ostringstream` (note the lack of automatic construction).

Comment: @WhozCraig I did not paste it, I just changed the format of the code in OP's question. What is the problem? I have not even looked at the link.

Comment: @tacp how the heck did that change? Check out the change log. its bizarre.

Comment: @WhozCraig how could I look at the log? I am happy to correct if I made any mistake.

Comment: @tacp no no, don't change anything. just click the `edited <time>` right above your name  just under the question to see the edit history.

Comment: @tacp I think what happened was while I was answering the OP updated the question right at the 5-min update window (that doesn't log changes), then you formatted it afterward and it only included your update. Just weird. I apologize if I seemed a little off-kilter. Hope you understand. Its important to keep the original content. I don't think you did anything wrong.

Comment: @WhozCraig I understand that.

Comment: You could always stray from the string stream route and use a variadic template and perfect forwarding. Something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f690f62362610c36324d6ac11bc6d5c3-29e182f7ca6e65f5df784fe9d3b6118a) should work and I know Boost has a form of variadic templates for C++03.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is this: `(std::stringstream() << f)`

If you read the reference to `std::stringstream`'s `operator<<(...)` you'll find that it is inherited from `std::ostream`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/

The problem is the `operator<<(...)` returns an `std::ostream` and therefore, when you pass `(std::stringstream() << f)` you are actually passing an `std::ostream` to a function that requires an `std::stringstream` (hence, the invalid initialization of stringstream from ostream)

To achieve what you want, exactly, you'll have to modify the way your macro works. Try something like this instead:

```
#define LOG_TEST(f) \
    do { std::stringstream s; \
         s << f; \
         log(__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, s); \
    } while (0)
```